# Does this PyList_Append(list, Py_BuildValue(...)) leak?

Tags: python, c

Does this leak?:

```
static PyObject* foo(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    PyObject* list = PyList_New(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        // leak? does PyList_Append increment ref of the temporary?
        PyList_Append(list, Py_BuildValue("i", 42)); 
    return list;
}
```

Though, I suppose it's better to do this, in any case?:

```
static PyObject* foo(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    PyObect* list = PyList_New(100);
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        PyList_SetItem(list, i, Py_BuildValue("i", 42));
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`PyList_Append` does indeed increment the reference counter, so, yes, the first example will leak.  `PyList_SetItem` does not, making it a weird exception.

The second option will be slightly more efficient because the list will be allocated to excatly the right size and Python does have to dynamically resize it as items are appended.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions!

Comment: Where is the python documentation does one find that PyList_Append increments the refcount of the stored object? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelSoulier I had the same issue, but found the call to Py_INCREF in the app1 function, which is called in PyList_Append. I did not see this in any documentation, but found it in the listobject.c file

Comment: What if I don't know the exact size of the list and I want to append without leaking? Should I Py_DecRef(my_object) after PyList_Append(list, my_object)? Does PyList_Append instantiate a new object with the same value or uses the reference of my_object?

Comment: @MichaelSoulier: It's the default assumption that the reference passed to a C function is borrowed, and if the function needs to save a reference, it will increment the refcount appropriately. PyList_Append follows this behavior, so its documentation needs no special note. PyList_SetItem does not follow this behavior, so the documentation specifically mentions that it steals a reference to the new element.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#ownership-rules